# How can I change the order of two arrays when one array is sorted?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

If I have:

`var arrayOne = ["dog", "cat", "hamster", "horse"]​`
and

`var arrayTwo = [3, 2, 4, 1]`

How can I assign `3` to `dog`, `2` to `cat`, `4` to `hamster`, and `1` to `horse` so that if I sort `arrayTwo` from biggest integer to smallest, it will automatically do that for `arrayOne` too. In result it would print out:

`var arrayOne = ["hamster", "dog", "cat", "horse"]`

`var arrayTwo = [4, 3, 2, 1]`

What code is easiest and simplest for this?

Thanks in Advance! :)

Comment: Keep them in one array, with a tuple, or another object (dictionary, custom struct/object, etc.). Don't keep 2 arrays that's exactly the best way to keep them desynchronized.

Comment: You better define an `Animal` struct or class with two properties: `id` and `name`. Arrays can get confusing really quick

Comment: This was interesting to try and by the time I came back, the question was closed but anywho... here's what I came up with: https://gist.github.com/staticVoidMan/19175de6ea9021eaa27d3b5cf4d432ba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite hard to "bind" the two variables together. You could do something like this:

```
let dict = [3: "dog", 2: "cat", 4: "hamster", 1: "horse"]

var arrayTwo = [3, 2, 4, 1] {
    willSet {
        // you should probably check whether arrayTwo still has the same elements here
        arrayOne = newValue.map { dict[$0]! }
    }
}
```

It is easier to zip the arrays and then sort by `arrayTwo`:

```
let result = zip(arrayOne, arrayTwo).sorted(by: { $0.1 > $1.1 })
```

Now, `result.map { $0.0 }` is your sorted array 1 and `result.map { $0.1 }` is your sorted array 2.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers! Sorry for the delay :( They are all very helpful.